# How to translate ARAnchor size to SpriteKit equivalent

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit, arkit

Question:

*How do I create a new SKSpriteNode that is the same height and width of the ARObjectAnchor.referenceObject.*

Context:

I'm currently fiddling with ARKit's new object detection feature and have working code to detect an object that I scanned in. When ARKit detects the object it provides a new ARAnchor of type ARObjectAnchor.

I know ARSCNView provides a projectPoint method, but I can't find any equivalent function for ARSKView. How can I map the ARObjectAnchor dimensions to the new Sprite?

Here's how I'm processing the detected object:

```
func view(_ view: ARSKView, didAdd node: SKNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    if let objectAnchor = anchor as? ARObjectAnchor {
        let width = objectAnchor.referenceObject.extent.x
        let height = objectAnchor.referenceObject.extent.y

        // How to translate above height/width to the below size? 

        let box = SKSpriteNode(color: .white, size: ???)
        node.addChild(box)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
let size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
let box = SKSpriteNode(color: .white, size: size)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

When I add a SKScene to my SCNPlane in my image recognition app, I do a * 10000 of the size of my SCNPlane (don't ask me why it's 10000 i have no idea) as follow

```
let toto = SCNNode(geometry: SCNPlane(width: 0.3, height: 0.1))
let sk = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 3000, height: 1000))
```

and for me it's the same size, try this out and tell me if it works for you !

Comment: I tried to scale it by 10,000 and the result was way too big. 1,000 works better for me, but this doesn't fully answer my question. I'm sure there's a proper way to transform the 3d coordinate system to 2d but I don't know how to do so.

Comment: Maybe it's because the size with 3D systems is in meters when in 2D it's in millimeters ?, the x1000 makes sense then